# como solucionar problemas en el update con senetencias preparadas

Tags: php, html, update, crud

estoy implementando update a mi sistema con sentencias preparadas pero el problema se presenta al querer actualizar un solo campo de la tabla. Si bien funciona al momento de actualizar todos los campos, no lo hace cuando quiero actualizar un campo solamente. ¿A que se debe este problema? espero que pueda tener alguna solución

este es el código del update

```
if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) 
  {

      $numFicha1 = $_POST['txt_num_fic'];

      $fecha1 = $_POST['txt_fec_fic'];
      $caso1 = $_POST['slt_cas_fic'];
      $materia1 = $_POST['slt_materia'];
      $valor1 = $_POST['txt_valor_fic'];
      $RutPro1 = $_POST['rut_abo'];
      $alcance1 = $_POST['ta_alc_fic'];
      $observacion1 = $_POST['ta_aco_fic'];
   
   
 if (!($sentencia = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE `fichas` SET `fechaingreso`= ? ,`tiposcasosid`= ? ,
     `materia`= ? ,`valor`= ? ,`rutabogado`= ? ,`alcance`= ? ,`descripcion`= ? WHERE numeroficha = '$numFicha'"))) {
      echo "Falló la preparación: (" . $conexion->errno . ") " . $conexion->error;
     }
     if (!$sentencia->bind_param("sisisss",$fecha1, $caso1, $materia1, $valor1, $RutPro1, $alcance1,
     $observacion1)) {
     echo "Falló la vinculación de parámetros: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
     }
     if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
     echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
     }
     $resultadoUpdate=mysqli_query($conexion, $update);
     $_SESSION['message']="Ficha Modificada Correctamente";
     $_SESSION['message_type']='primary';
     header("Location: casostributarios.php");
     exit;
    
  
  }
```

Comment: En donde estás asignando la consulta a `$update` ??? El mysqli_query esta tratando de correr una variable $update que no la veo asignada.

Comment: por ejemplo $update = "Update...." así te refieres ?

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump($update)` antes del `mysqli_query`, que consulta estás haciendo ?

Comment: vi que no estaba asignada en ningún lado, puse el var_dump antes como me dijiste pero no me muestra nada, de dos campos para arriba si me actualiza la consulta pero no un solo campo. Estoy medio enredado, he llevado tiempo tratando de solucionarlo

Comment: cual es el error por pantalla, te sale algo??? cuando se te pregunta algo; debes actualizar tu post y agregar el resultado de la prueba

Comment: no me sale ningun error por pantalla, simplemente no actualiza el campo que quiero pero si actualizo mas de uno actualiza

Comment: lo que quiero lograr es que solo me actualice un solo campo si así lo requiero y no tener que actualizar todos los campos solo para poder actualizar uno solo

Comment: y por que no haces un armado dinamico??? valida que campos cambiaron y en base a eso haces un update y si quieres puedes hacer un log de los campos que el usuario actualizo...

Comment: Segundo las sentencias preparadas están enfocadas al insert y no al update... eso quiere decir que si quieres actualizar dinamicamente la columna o campo que se actualizo no te recomiento reciclar la sentencia preparada.

Comment: lo he intentado de esta forma también

$update = "UPDATE `fichas` SET `alcance`='$alcance1',`descripcion`='$observacion1',`fechaingreso`='$fecha1',
                 `materia`='$materia1',`rutabogado`='$RutPro1',`tiposcasosid`='$caso1',`valor`='$valor1' WHERE numeroficha='$numFicha1'";
                                     
                                     
 
    $resultadoUpdate=mysqli_query($conexion, $update);
    $_SESSION['message']="Ficha Modificada Correctamente";
    $_SESSION['message_type']='primary';
    header("Location: casostributarios.php");
    exit;
pero nada